# problems in understanding torch.backward function

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to rewrite a program that massively uses pytorch from scratch, but I need to understand how the backward function works:

```
class RBM(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,
               n_vis=784,
               n_hin=500,
               k=5):
        super(RBM, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_hin,n_vis)*1e-2)
        self.v_bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_vis))
        self.h_bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_hin))
        self.k = k

   def sample_from_p(self,p):
       return F.relu(torch.sign(p - Variable(torch.rand(p.size()))))

   def v_to_h(self,v):
        p_h = F.sigmoid(F.linear(v,self.W,self.h_bias)) # sigmoid((batch, n_vis) @ (n_hin, n_vis))
        sample_h = self.sample_from_p(p_h)
        return p_h,sample_h

   def h_to_v(self,h):
        p_v = F.sigmoid(F.linear(h,self.W.t(),self.v_bias))
        sample_v = self.sample_from_p(p_v)
        return p_v,sample_v

   def forward(self,v):
        pre_h1,h1 = self.v_to_h(v) # v.shape: (batch, n_vis)

        h_ = h1
        for _ in range(self.k):
            pre_v_,v_ = self.h_to_v(h_)
            pre_h_,h_ = self.v_to_h(v_)

        return v,v_

   def free_energy(self,v):
        vbias_term = v.mv(self.v_bias)
        wx_b = F.linear(v,self.W,self.h_bias)
        hidden_term = wx_b.exp().add(1).log().sum(1)
        return (-hidden_term - vbias_term).mean()
```

This is the code i have to translate. Nothing special, already made it.

Then,

```
rbm = RBM(k=1)
train_op = optim.SGD(rbm.parameters(),0.1)

for epoch in range(10):
    loss_ = []
    for _, (data,target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = Variable(data.view(-1,784))
        sample_data = data.bernoulli()

        v,v1 = rbm(sample_data)
        loss = rbm.free_energy(v) - rbm.free_energy(v1)
        loss_.append(loss.data)
        train_op.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        train_op.step()

    print("Training loss for {} epoch: {}".format(epoch, np.mean(loss_)))
```

What I understood is that every parameter of rbm(w, v_bias, h_bias) has a gradient, who gets calculated with the backward function and then the train_op.step() updates the parameter values.

What I don't get, however, is how the backward function works, since the loss output is something like

`tensor(3.2397, grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)`

So, how to calculate the gradient with backward?